# Android studio custom gradle launch command

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I would like the APK installed on the device to be generated using a custom command:

```
./gradlew clean assemble -PdisablePreDex
```

But I don't want to go to command line and then use adb install name.apk.
I'm using Android Studio and I want to configure the run configuration to run with this command?

Comment: by mistake I have removed flag of duplicate, but it is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33216248/passing-p-parameters-to-gradle-from-android-studio

Answer (score 4):

1. Click on the dropdown list to the left of the "Run" button.
2. Click on "Edit configurations..."
3. Click on "Gradle" then on the "+" button.
4. Configure your custom "Run" script

[image: screenshot]

Comment: That I did. But how do i get this line to run? I've managed to get the clean and assemble to run by adding gradle-aware make on the before launch. But i cannot add the option -PdisablePreDex

Comment: it doesn't work if you put `-PdisablePreDex` in "Script parameters" field ?

Comment: Seems like everything you're putting in the gradle task configuration is assumed to be an actual gradle task and not a parameter.  Seems like an oversight.