# Passing -P parameters to gradle from android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Is there a functionality inside android studio to do things like this.
Basically my gradle script reads parameter named version based on which it sets dependency version of a certain library.
So when I do gradlew -Pversion=‘1.2.3' I get this string inside gradle. But this only works if I invoke gradle from console.

Is there a way to pass parameters to gradle when started using configuration for project inside Android Studio (pressing little play triangle)?

NOTE:I did find Gradle VM options and Script prameters under default configs but adding -Pversion=‘1.2.3' there doesn't seem to have an effect.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In order to provide parameter to `run` option of Android Studio you should setup them under AndroidStudios Compile Preferences

AndroidStudio > Preferences...

Under Compiler: ComandLineOptions
[image]

Comment: On AS 3.0.1, this worked for me, and allows Instant Run capability while passing gradle properties. It's unfortunate that this must be set globally, and cannot be set per run configuration.  Also, as @KMP answered, using gradle task directly with a property works, but it breaks Instant Run for me.

Comment: Instant Run is overrated. :)

Comment: For me it worked with not -P but -D like -DminSDK=23

Answer (score 13):

Run > Edit Configurations..

[image]

Replace "abcdef" in Script parameters by your params.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working in my case. I want to pass the parameter to gradle when using Android Application configuration (first option on the left in your screenshot) i don't want to run Gradle task directly.

Answer (score 10):

For example let's try to pass server base endpoint while building project. First we need to define a method which gets url and sets it

```
def serverUrl = "https://mydefaulturl.com"
task(runProgram){
   if(project.hasProperty("url")){
       serverUrl = url;
   }
}
```

In your buildTypes create your base url with this value:

```
debug{
   buildConfigField("java.lang.String","BASE_URL","$serverUrl")
}
```

Now we can pass debug build an url and use it.

You can build your project from terminal with the command below:

```
./gradlew installDebug task runProgram '-Purl="https://yournewurl.com"'
```

Comment: What is the use of adding a field to build config here?

Comment: if you use two or more different urls for test and production you can generate your base url with build variants or build types. before production it's not a good case commenting in or commenting out some critical variables such as base url.

Comment: if you add these codes to your build gradle and run gradlew code from terminal in android studio, this'll be a way to do within the android studio. :)

Comment: @Burf2000 The effort to try it out would have been less then writing your comment...

Comment: i'm not sure why people down vote my answer but the code is working and i'm still using it in production :)

Comment: this is done in the app gradle file or the project gradle file?

Comment: app gradle file

Comment: @ABS this answer should work, do not rely too much on GUI

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS Well the question is asking how to do it from "Android Studio". So it does not really answers it.

Comment: @ABS and you can do it using "Android Studio" terminal, WDYT?

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS Yeah sure. I guess it makes the cut :) I answered it this way because I am used to use the play button in Android Studio, so that's basically makes it more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Put `version="1.2.3"` in gradle.properties or under

```
buildscript {
    ext{
        version="1.2.3"
    }
...
}
```