# ANDROID : Gradle passing in a parameter e.g serverURL

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I would like to run Gradle and pass in a server url so that I can have different endpoints for my Android App to look at.

I have followed this post [Passing -P parameters to gradle from android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33216248/passing-p-parameters-to-gradle-from-android-studio/36509321)

But when I deploy it to my pipeline, it can't see the task.

Error:

```
SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
[command]C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C "C:\vstsagent\A1\_work\3\s\ftg\gradlew.bat task setBaseUrl "-Purl=https://blabla.com/api/Graph" jacocoRootReport"
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

> Configure project :app
app: 'annotationProcessor' dependencies won't be recognized as kapt annotation processors. Please change the configuration name to 'kapt' for these artifacts: 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'setBaseUrl' not found in root project 'ftg'.
```

The Gradle task is in my App build.gradle

```
def serverUrl = "https://bla.com/api/Graph"

task setBaseUrl(){
    group = "build"
    if(project.hasProperty("url")){
        serverUrl = url
    }
}
```

I can call the task locally by doing

```
gradle task setBaseUrl -Purl=https://bla.com/api/Graph
```

Answer (score 0):

This actually turned out that the pipeline (Azure Devops) was not pulling in the latest Gradle files even though it was building the branch.  It was using the Gradle files from Develop but the code from FeatureXYZ